# Describe $\text{Re} \frac{1}{z}=1$, $z$ Complex Number

Tags: complex-numbers

I would like to describe this equation on the XY Plane, where $z$ is a Complex Number
$$\text{Re}\left( \frac{1}{z}\right)=1$$ 
What I did is to get the Real part:
$$z=x+y\mathbb{i} \rightarrow\frac{1}{x+y\mathbb{i}}\cdot\frac{x-y\mathbb{i}}{x-y\mathbb{i}}=\frac{x-y\mathbb{i}}{x^2+y^2}$$
so the Real part is:
$$\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}=1$$
I would like to get advice how to continue from here. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x$ and $y$ cannot both be zero, multiply by $x^2+y^2$ to obtain
$$
x=x^2+y^2
$$
Then we have 
$$
x^2-x+y^2=0
$$
Then we complete the square, 
$$
x^2-x+\frac{1}{4}+y^2=\frac{1}{4}
$$
which yields
$$
\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+y^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2
$$
a circle of radius $1/2$ centered at $(1/2,0)$.